# How to access all dictionary keys in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am passing a dictionary like below to my template:

```
mydict={6:"a",9:"b"}
```

Now I want to check in template if a particular value is in dictionary key.Something like:

```
{% if i in mydict.items.keys %} ok {% endif %}
```

I want to display "ok" if i is either 6 or 9, however the above syntax does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: check without using the keys, just `if i in mydict`

Comment: I added it as a proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check without using the items.keys, just

```
{% if i in mydict %} ok {% endif %}
```

or, if you really want to use keys

```
{% if i in mydict.keys %} ok {% endif %}
```